# SQL query executed through Windows batch: missing table

Tags: sql, postgresql, batch-file, postgresql-9.4

I execute a SQL query (for PostgreSQL) via psql.exe inside a Windows batch. I get an error I can't explain, saying that a FROM clause is missing for a table that is not called within the query (see below). When I search in the batch file for `geo_c3_0_3_mo` table, the string is not found...

Any idea on this kind of issue?

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

If I copy-paste the query from the batch file into a pgAdminIII SQL query window, the query runs perfectly and no error message is returned.

When I remove one of the subqueries, the error either disappear or mention another badly written table name (for instance: `missing FROM-clause for table "geoc__0_3_mo"`)... **It seems more and more that the issue comes from the length of the line (19,413 characters!)**. To me, it is not possible to write the query on several lines within a batch file, like inside a pgAdminIII SQL query window. The solution would be to keep the query inside a `*.sql` file and to call that file from the batch file.

Comment: My best guess would be a missing `FROM` clause entry for table "geo_c3_0_3_mo".

Comment: from the position `st_intersects(geo_c3_0_3` I'd say syntaxis wrongly interpreted - please put whole query, not a screenshot

Comment: I've checked it out so many times but no `FROM` clause missing. The thing is that table `geo_c3_0_3_mo` **is not called** in the query (whereas `geo_c_3_0_3_mo` is - several times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the query to a tempfile in your batch, then execute it with `psql -f`. This will bypass command-line length issues.

Comment: Good idea! But I still have problems writing the query in a temp file for the string is too long... `echo "My query" > temp.txt` writes `echo command activated` in `temp.txt`. If I reduce the length of the string, it writes it properly...

Comment: @wiltomap Use multiple `echo`'s to append to the file with `>>`. You can also use cmd.exe's line-ending-escape `^` to write it with linebreaks.